# How to spontaneously send data with Actix in Rust

Tags: rust, server-sent-events, actix-web

I am completely new to Rust and Actix so apologies if this is a stupid question but i cant seem to find any information or examples on how this would be done.

I am trying to build a server with Actix in rust that is able to sent SSEs to connected clients. Ive followed the code in this [example](https://github.com/actix/examples/tree/master/server-sent-events) and it seems to work fine but what i want to do is for my server to decide to suddenly send SSEs and not when its driven through client interactions. Right now the only way to send an SSE is if a client sends it through a URL call which actix has a handler for. What if i have some other part of my server, perhaps another worker thread that reads data from a disk or another dll and then based on that decides to suddenly send SSEs to all clients?

I find it hard to see how thats supposed to work because if you want access to your mutable data that holds the registered SSE clients, it needs a copy/clone of the mutable data wrapped in an arc. Could someone give some guidelines on how i should proceed in getting actix to send SSE data thats not client driven from the web?

Comment: maybe you need websocket?@pSquared

Answer (score 0):

No matter where the event is coming from, you WILL need the client to begin the transaction. What you can do is have all clients make a request on startup to some endpoint such as "/sse" that won't send anything at that point but stays open. The handler will need to keep track of who is this client and stay open to send updates in the future.

In practice what this means is you can use something like https://tokio.rs/tokio/tutorial/channels to await in the handler for messages in the channel, then store the transmitter end of the channel in some shared app state. Now, from any part of the app you have access to the transmitter end of the channel, you can send arbitrary data and have the handler process it and send any necessary messages back to the client.

```
/sse handler
------------
|- Incoming connections
|  |  |
|  |  | ...
1  2  3
|  .  .
|
\---- 1. Create new channel
    - 2. Associate transmitter with user in app state
    - 3. Loop
      - 4. Await next message in channel
      - 5. Process message and send event to client
      - 6. goto: Loop


background process
------------------
...
 1. something happens! we need to notify user 12345
 2. find transmitter for user 12345 in app state
 3. send item in channel
```

Comment: I realize my question is too broad. I am aware of the process of creating and storing the channels with the client, i was doing that following https://github.com/actix/examples/tree/master/server-sent-events but my issue was actually with threads and strange thread behaviour. I had a thread in main that would spawn and keep running before creating the server and that caused issues. I moved it to the broadcast struct and then it was fine. Dont know why. But i guess thats how i would solve my issue. Spawn threads that will do work inside the shared struct.